# Navfn strange Behaviour

Tags: ros, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm tunning the navigation stack for my robot, but nafvn is displaying a strange behaviour, sometimes it cannot plan when in narrow places.

Here are some screenshoots

In this case the navfn cannot plan

Anybody has an idea why this is happening

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29634/navfn-strange-behaviour/) by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2013-05-05**:
I am seeing the same behavior, but I can't post a screenshot. In tight areas, the plan starts right after the tight area instead of  starting from the robot. Edit: Increasing cost_scaling_factor from 0.1 to 10 fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think navfn is quite simple in that it only plans for circular robots. Your's seems a bit lengthy and rectangular. This would lead to a circumference that just doesn't fit through the passage.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-29**:
There have also been some observed bugs in navfn where it's sensitive to initial conditions.